# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'stdout' and 'stderr'

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, typeerror

I encountered the following error while running a program `extract_frame_and_wav_multiprocess.py`, which is designed to extract audio and frames from the videos in dataset `MSRVTT`.
Here is the error message from the program:

```bash
(valor) xxx:/VALOR/utils$ python extract_frame_and_wav_multiprocess.py                                                                                                                                                                           
0%|                                       | 0/10005 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Exception in thread Thread-3:                                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                   
File "/anaconda3/envs/valor/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner                                                    
self.run()                                                                                                                                                                       
File "/anaconda3/envs/valor/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run                                                                                          
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                                                                                                                                        
File "/anaconda3/envs/valor/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 576, in _handle_results                                                                   
task = get()                                                                                                                                                                     
File "/anaconda3/envs/valor/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 256, in recv                                                                        
return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())                                                                                                                                  
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'stdout' and 'stderr'
```

This is the location indicated by the error message(in the file `/anaconda3/envs/valor/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py`):

```py
    def recv(self):
        """Receive a (picklable) object"""
        self._check_closed()
        self._check_readable()
        buf = self._recv_bytes()
        return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
```

The following program is the python program `extract_frame_and_wav_multiprocess.py` being executed:

```py
import os
import os.path as P
import ffmpeg
import json
import tqdm
import numpy as np
import threading
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess



### change diffenrent datasets
input_path = '../datasets/msrvtt/raw_videos'
output_path = '../datasets/msrvtt/testt'
data_list = os.listdir(input_path)

def execCmd(cmd):
    r = os.popen(cmd)
    text = r.read()
    r.close()
    return text

def pipline(video_path, video_probe, output_dir, fps, sr, duration_target):
    video_name = os.path.basename(video_path)
    audio_name = video_name.replace(".mp4", ".wav")
    video_name = video_name.replace(".mp4", "")


    #extract video frames fps
    fps_frame_dir = P.join(output_dir, f"frames_fps{fps}", video_name)
    os.makedirs(fps_frame_dir, exist_ok=True)
    cmd = "ffmpeg -loglevel error -i {} -vsync 0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps={:.02f} -qscale:v 2 {}/frame_%04d.jpg".format(
              video_path, fps, fps_frame_dir)
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

    # Extract Audio
    sr_audio_dir = P.join(output_dir,f"audio_{sr}hz")
    os.makedirs(sr_audio_dir, exist_ok=True)
    audio_file_path = P.join(sr_audio_dir, audio_name)
    cmd = "ffmpeg -i {} -loglevel error -f wav -vn -ac 1 -ab 16k -ar {} -y {}".format(
            video_path, sr, audio_file_path)
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)


def extract_thread(video_id):
    
    video_name = os.path.join(input_path, video_id)
    if not os.path.exists(video_name):
        return
    probe = ffmpeg.probe(video_name)
    pipline(video_name, probe, output_path, fps=4, sr=22050, duration_target=10)


def extract_all(video_ids, thread_num, start):
    length = len(video_ids)
    print(length)
    with Pool(thread_num) as p:
        list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(extract_thread, video_ids), total=length))

if __name__=='__main__':
    thread_num = 50
    start = 0

    print(len(data_list))
    extract_all(data_list, thread_num, start)
```

It's strange that similar errors did not occur when processing the `DiDeMo` video dataset, but they are encountered when handling the `MSRVTT` dataset. (Is this related to the fact that the `DiDeMo` dataset doesn't have audio?)

Comment: A a side note: someone could inject shell code placed in a file name. Consider to give the command as a list with `shell=False`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to version compatibility issues with dependencies such as Python, when calling `subprocess.Popen` within the `ffmpeg.probe` module, even though we input parameters like stdout and stderr, it still throws errors indicating missing stdout, etc. Therefore, we have omitted the step of using the `ffmpeg.probe` command to record information.
we can change the original code:

```py
    probe = ffmpeg.probe(video_name)
    pipline(video_name, probe, output_path, fps=1, sr=22050, duration_target=10)
```

into the following code:

```py
    # probe = ffmpeg.probe(video_name)
    pipline(video_name, None, output_path, fps=1, sr=22050, duration_target=10)
```